# Kubernetes ingress prefix path issue

Tags: path, http-status-code-404, kubernetes-ingress, prefix, ingress-controller

I have nginx ingress controller deployed using helm, a simple nginx pod, service and ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: all-app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: example.com # I have my own domain name
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /nginx-test
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-test
            port:
              number: 80
```

describe svc and ingress:

```
kubectl describe svc nginx-test  
Name:              nginx-test
Namespace:         default
Labels:            run=nginx-test
Annotations:       cloud.google.com/neg: {"ingress":true}
Selector:          run=nginx-test
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.46.128.187
IPs:               10.46.128.187
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         10.46.1.2:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

kubectl describe ingress all-app-ingress  
Name:             all-app-ingress
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        default
Address:          34.122.42.46
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host               Path  Backends
  ----               ----  --------
  example.com  
                     /nginx-test   nginx-test:80 (10.46.1.2:80)
Annotations:         nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /nginx-test
Events:
  Type    Reason          Age                  From                      Message
  ----    ------          ----                 ----                      -------
  Normal  AddedOrUpdated  13m (x29 over 2d1h)  nginx-ingress-controller  Configuration for default/all-app-ingress was added or updated
```

If I try to access the app http://example.com/nginx-test I get **404 Not Found**

But if I use the root prefix path:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: all-app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: example.com # I have my own domain name
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-test
            port:
              number: 80
```

Now I can access the the **Welcome to nginx!** page.
Hmmm.. Not sure why the root path works well here, but prefix subpath doesn't?

Get logs from nginx ingress controller when use /nginx-test path:

```
kubectl logs nginx-controller-01-nginx-ingress-6bb9c56f6d-dvm8c | tail
3.135.248.93 - - [01/Mar/2023:23:09:31 +0000] "GET /resources/.git/config HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2" "-"
3.135.248.93 - - [01/Mar/2023:23:09:31 +0000] "GET /system/.git/config HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2" "-"
3.135.248.93 - - [01/Mar/2023:23:09:31 +0000] "GET /src/.git/config HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2" "-"
2023/03/01 23:18:39 [error] 209#209: *2800 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 167.250.111.166, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
167.250.111.166 - - [01/Mar/2023:23:18:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
76.37.41.134 - - [01/Mar/2023:23:18:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
2023/03/01 23:18:47 [error] 209#209: *2801 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 76.37.41.134, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2023/03/01 23:19:04 [error] 209#209: *2802 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 138.68.47.85, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
138.68.47.85 - - [01/Mar/2023:23:19:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36" "127.0.0.1"
138.68.47.85 - - [01/Mar/2023:23:19:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Logs from nginx ingress controller when "/" root path used:

```
 kubectl logs nginx-controller-01-nginx-ingress-6bb9c56f6d-dvm8c | 
tail

73.202.54.6 - - [01/Mar/2023:23:37:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
73.202.54.6 - - [01/Mar/2023:23:37:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
73.202.54.6 - - [01/Mar/2023:23:37:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
73.202.54.6 - - [01/Mar/2023:23:37:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

P.S. domain masked everywhere with example.com